jsonata merge two arrays to single array of object
how can to merge two arrays to a single array of object
here's a sample source
{"event_date": ["a","b","c"],"values" : [1,2,3]}
i would like to have this format
{
    "data" : [
        { 
            "date": "a",
            "value": 1
        },
        { 
            "date": "b",
            "value": 2
        },
        { 
            "date": "c",
            "value": 3
        }       
    ]
}


{
  "data": $map($.event_date, function($v, $i) { 
    {
      "date": $v,
      "value": $.values[$i]
    }
  }) 
}

Playground link: https://jsonatastudio.com/playground/6bb3385e
